# `UILabel' could not be found

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript, ngui

When I Place my Demo.cs in Standard Assets Folder I am Getting this error:

`Assets/Standard Assets/Demo.cs(130,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'UILabel' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?`

and when I place Demo.cs Assets Folder above error get solved 
but I cant call any method of Demo.cs from my another Demo1.js

Gives error:
`Assets/Scripts/Demo1.js(81,20): BCE0018: The name 'Demo' does not denote a valid type ('not found').`

any solution ?

Comment: I think UILabel is part of the NGUI framework. If you're using NGUI you should move its files into Standard Assets, or move Demo.cs out of Standard Assets.

Comment: SOLVED
Copied all NGUI stuff in standard assest except one folder "Editor" which i Kept in Assests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to access NGUI components from unityscript 
Got solution from below link

http://www.tasharen.com/forum/index.php?topic=6.0

Answer (score 0):

The UILabel class you are looking for is likely part of NGUI.

Import NGUI into your current project from the asset store (assuming you've bought it) and Unity will find the class.